# Does the integrability of $\log(f(x))$ imply $f(x)$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x):(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\int_a^b\log{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, can we claim that $0<f(x)<M<\infty$ a.e.. Why and why not?

Comment: Nice descriptive title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f\colon (0,1)\to \Bbb R, x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Why? Could you kindly give more details?

Comment: @Paul I see you have relatively high rep. Do you suspect I'm making something wrong? I claim the statement is false and I'm providing a counterexample.

Comment: @GitGud Your answer is correct.

Comment: I like hint more than answer.